How to sync background color of MaterialToolbar to BottomAppBar?
According to the specs from material3, the background color for BottomAppBar and MaterialToolbar is md.sys.color.surface-container. When I set android:background="?colorSurfaceContainer" or style="@style/Widget.Material3.BottomAppBar" to both of them, the real colors are #f1ecf1 and #f2ecf6. What do I need to do to change the background color of MaterialToolab to #f2ecf6? Exclude hardcoded hex.


I'm not sure I should be asking this depending on the code you've already posted, but could you please provide some more code? The code in the context of your problem...?

@Linus There is no code. It's just pure style that I've tried to apply to the views.

So in order to help you I am supposed to write all the surrounding code myself? I'm downvoting this, apologies

Here you can find an answer if you are using Flutter:
ANSWER 4 FLUTTER
Here the documentation from Android
DOC ANDROID
On the documentation they say:

Do not use the android:background attribute or call
BottomAppBar.setBackground because the BottomAppBar manages its
background internally. Instead use app:backgroundTint.
To enable color theming for menu items you will also need to set the
materialThemeOverlay attribute to a ThemeOverlay which sets the
colorControlNormal attribute to the correct color. For example, if the
background of the BottomAppBar is colorSurface, as it is in the
default style, you should set materialThemeOverlay to
@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Surface.

You can see the method:
setBackgroundTint

I think is what you are refering too.
WHen you inflate the layout you should have a reference to it if you are using kotlin. You can call the function above from it to change the Tint.
